# Truncate or round?

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to display a calculated number to only 2 decimals without rounding.

Examples:

```
23.456 is shown as 23.45
45.5634 is shown as 45.56.
```

Do I need to truncate or round the number?

```
MyWSTarget.Cells(i + ofst - 2, 9).Value = _
MyWSTarget.Cells(i + ofst + k - i - 1, 12).Value * MyWSTarget.Cells(i + ofst - 2, 2).Value, 2)
```

Comment: Wrap your math expression with `round(your long expression,2)`

Comment: @ScottCraner - That isn't going to return `23.45` from `23.456`.

Comment: @Jeeped fair enough. I read the title for round and went with it.

Comment: If you want to get rid of everything after two decimal places. Use the rounddown function. Same arguments as the round but instead of round type rounddown

Comment: Welcome to SO.  This is not a free code-writing service but exists to help others with code or functions they are trying to develop.  Where is your code showing how you applied `truncate` or `round`?  What were the actual results?  What were the expected results?  In your question, you do not indicate how you want to handle negative numbers, and this will make a significant difference.   Please read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); and also [How to Provide an Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks I will give those a read over the next time I post something. I did not expect anyone do all the work for me. If anything I would have loved a good reference to learn more about it. These guys were very helpful and I really appreciate it since I'm a Beginner/Newb to VBA. I did not mention negative numbers because that would never be an occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of options...

1: Split your data using the '.' as a delimiter; keep the first bit, add the dot back in, and add the first two "characters" from the decimal:

```
ActiveCell.Value = Split(ActiveCell.Value, ".")(0) & "." & Left(Split(ActiveCell.Value, ".")(1), 2)
```

2: Multiply your value by 100 and take the integer at that point (removes decimal places), then divide by 100 again:

```
ActiveCell.Value = (Int(ActiveCell.Value * 100)) / 100
```